# How to find the number of ordered pairs $(A,B)$, where $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $S$ and $A$ is a proper subset of $B$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Question-> Let $S$ be a set of $n$ consecutive natural numbers. How to find the number of ordered pairs $(A,B)$, where $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $S$ and $A$ is a proper subset of $B$.

Number of subsets -> $2^n$ --> here $2^8$
number of proper subsets -> $(2^n)-1$

then how the answer is $3^n-2^n$ ?

Please explain..

Comment: Wow, I have a deja vu. I feel like this exact question was posted a year or two ago.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the complement.

**Hint:** There are $2^n$ pairs of subsets where $A = B$, which is a subset of $S$.

This follows from the rule of product, because there are 2 possibilities for each element.

**Hint:** There are $3^n$ pairs of subsets where $A$ is a subset of $B$, which is a subset of $S$.

This follows from the rule of product, because there are 3 possibilities for each element.

Answer (score 2):

When you find sets $A$ and $B$ such that $A\subsetneqq B\subseteq S$, you’re really dividing $S$ into three parts: things that are in $A$ (and of course also in $B$), things that are in $B$ but not $A$, and things that are not in $B$. In other words, evern element of $S$ belongs to exactly one of the sets $A$, $B\setminus A$, and $S\setminus B$. Conversely, if you divide $S$ into parts $X,Y$, and $Z$, you can let $A=X$ and $B=X\cup Y$ to get a pair of subsets $A$ and $B$ of $S$ such that $A\subseteq B$.

There’s nothing in the statement of the problem that prevents $A$ from being empty, so there’s no harm in letting $X=\varnothing$. There’s nothing that prevents $B$ from being all of $S$, so there’s no harm in letting $Z=\varnothing$. But we’re told that $A\subsetneqq B$, so $B\setminus A\ne\varnothing$. Thus, we must ensure that the part $Y$ of our $3$-way split of $S$ gets at least one member.

In order to build such a division of $S$ into $3$ parts, you can go through $S$ one element at a time, assigning each element in turn to $X$, $Y$, or $Z$. That’s a sequence of $n$ $3$-way choices, so by the [multiplication principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) it can be made in $3^n$ different ways. That is, there are $3^n$ ways to divide up $S$ into the $3$ parts $X$, $Y$, and $Z$, from which, as noted above, we get $A$ and $B$ by setting $A=X$ and $B=X\cup Y$.

However, that calculation failed to take into account the requirement that $Y$ be non-empty. How many of these unwanted divisions are there? They are essentially just divisions of $S$ into **two** parts, $X$ and $Z$, and the same reasoning that we used in the previous paragraph shows that there must be $2^n$ of them. Subtracting them, we find that there are $3^n-2^n$ divisions of $S$ into $3$ parts $X,Y$, and $Z$ with $Y\ne\varnothing$, so that when we set $A=X$ and $B=X\cup Y$, $A$ really is a **proper** subset of $B$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ be pairwise disjoint subsets of $S$ whose union is $S$. Set $A=X$, $B=X\cup Y$. Then the pair $(A,B)$ has the right property, except that if $B=A$ then $A$ is not a **proper** subset of $B$.

Conversely, any pair $(A,B)$ such that $A$ is a subset of $B$ uniquely determines a partition of $S$ into pairwise disjoint subsets $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ by the rule $X=A$, $Y=B\setminus A$, and $Z$ equal to the rest.

We first count the number of ways to partition $S$ into three pairwise disjoint subsets. This is just the number of functions from $S$ to the set $\{1,2,3\}$. So there are $3^n$ ways to do the partioning

Now we throw away the number of "bad" partitions where $Y=\emptyset$. This is just the number of ways to divide $S$ into $2$ sets. There are $2^n$ ways to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Fix the the cardinality of $B$, and find how many sets $A$ are there such that $A\subset B$? The answer is $\mathcal{P}(B)-1$.

Now we just need to sum over all subsets of $S$, $$N=\sum_{B\subseteq S}\left(\mathcal P(B)-1\right)=-2^n+\sum_{B\subseteq S}\mathcal P(B)$$

Since $\mathcal P(B)=2^{|B|}$ we get $$N=-2^n+\sum_{B\subseteq S} 2^{|B|}=-2^n+\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{|B|=k}2^{|B|} $$
The question ''How many subsets of $S$ are there with caridinality $k$'' rise up here. And the answer is $n$ choose $k$. Hence $$N=-2^n+\sum_{k=1}^n{n \choose k}2^k=3^n-2^n$$
Because $$3^n=(1+2)^n=\sum_{k=1}^n{n \choose k}2^k$$
Which follows form the binomial theorem.

Answer (score 0):

We have Two sets $A$ and $B$ such that $A \subset B \subseteq S$. We can write it as $A \subseteq B \text{ and } A \neq B\text{ and } B \subseteq S$.

$n(X) =$ counts of ordered pairs for $X$

$\begin{align}
A \subseteq B \text{ and } A \neq B\text{ and } B \subseteq S &= \overline{\overline{A \subseteq B \text{ and } A \neq B\text{ and } B \subseteq S}} \cr
&= \text{Total} - n(A \not\subseteq B \displaystyle \cup A = B \displaystyle\cup B \nsubseteq S) \cr
&= \quad n(A \subseteq B \displaystyle \cap B \subseteq S) \cr &\quad- n(A \not\subseteq B \displaystyle \cup A = B \displaystyle \cup B \nsubseteq S)
\end{align}$

$\begin{align}
n(A \subseteq B \displaystyle \cap B \subseteq S) &= n(A \subseteq B \subseteq S)
\end{align}$

For $n(A \subseteq B \subseteq S)$, we have following options possible for an element

1. $x \in A \ \displaystyle\cap \ x \in B$
2. $x \not\in A \ \displaystyle\cap \ x \in B$
3. $x \not\in A \ \displaystyle\cap \ x \not\in B$

For $n$ such elements we will have $3^{n}$ possibilities.

$\begin{align}
n(A \not\subseteq B \displaystyle \cup A = B \displaystyle \cup B \nsubseteq S) &= n(x \in A \displaystyle \cap x \not\in B \displaystyle \cup A=B \displaystyle \cup x \in B \displaystyle \cap x \not\in S) \cr
&= n(\varnothing \displaystyle\cup A=B \displaystyle\cup \varnothing) \cr
&= n(A=B)
\end{align}$

For $n(A = B)$, we have following options possible for an element

1. $x \in A \ \displaystyle\cap \ x \in B$
2. $x \not\in A \ \displaystyle\cap \ x \not\in B$

For $n$ such elements we will have $2^{n}$ possibiities.

$n(A \subset B \subseteq S) = \bf{3^n-2^n}$